# Probability of an Event Occurring Over X Years Given Individual Annual Probabilities of the Event Occurring

Tags: probability

I feel like I'm making this far more complicated, but its been a while since I've last done any significant amount of probability and stats related math.

I'm trying to determine the overall probability of an event (failure) occurring within a 5 year window.

I have the probability of failure given that the equipment has survived to the next year.

For example:
P(Failure in Year 1) = 2.24%
P(Failure in Year 2) = 2.44%
P(Failure in Year 3) = 2.66%
P(Failure in Year 4) = 2.89%
P(Failure in Year 5) = 3.13%

I'm trying to determine the probability of the event occurring in the next 5 years.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The probability of failure can be seen as 1-(prob of success). The probability of success can be seen as (1-.0224)(1-.0244)(1-.0266)(1-.0289)(1-.0313). If you do the math it is about a .12667 chance of failure.